# Power BI :: calculate delta for baseline of a specific date

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

**SCENARIO:** Azure App Services have high cost on the cloud.

That's why at the end of November 2022 we put in place a cost reduction. As per the 30 of November 2022 the costs were at 83.63 per day. The day after they dropped to 48.22 per day:

[image]

**GOAL:** I would like to calculate the delta to highlight the success of the cost reduction

This is the DAX that I use to calculate the costs of App Services:

```
Savings App Service  = 
CALCULATE(SUM('Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency]), 
FILTER ( 'Usage details', 'Usage details'[meterCategory] = "Azure App Service" 
&& CONTAINSSTRING('Usage details'[meterName.1], "v2") 
&& ('Usage details'[subscriptionName] = "devqa"
|| 'Usage details'[subscriptionName] = "presales"
|| 'Usage details'[subscriptionName] = "sandbox")
 ))
```

It's all about line 2: `CALCULATE(SUM('Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency]),` this, for now, calculate the actual costs.

What I need to do now is to calculate a fixed baseline based on the date of 30 November 2022. The code [should](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/DAX-Commands-and-Tips/Calculation-on-cost-based-on-specific-date/m-p/2944814) look like:

```
Realised Testing = 
CALCULATE(sum('Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency]),FILTER(ALL('Usage details'[date].[Date]) = "30/11/2022") - SUM('Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency])
FILTER ( 'Usage details', 'Usage details'[meterCategory] = "Azure App Service" 
&& CONTAINSSTRING('Usage details'[meterName.1], "v2") 
&& ('Usage details'[subscriptionName] = "devqa"
|| 'Usage details'[subscriptionName] = "presales"
|| 'Usage details'[subscriptionName] = "sandbox")
 ))
```

But I receive an error that says `The Syntax for 'FILTER' is incorrect`:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

If creating a baseline based on the 30 of November is not possible also calculating the AVG of the whole month of November is a valid solution for me.

Thank you.

**EDIT:** Hi David I have updated 2 new files

- [Raw Data](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArldK_gE2gPUkch-2ANoTw2Hh8GBhQ?e=E8Z4k3)
- [.pbix](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArldK_gE2gPUkch91n_p4LyFz4v_Rg?e=rFqDxg)

While your code it looks like it's working the numbers are decreasing every month.

[image]

In February we have definitely saved more money than in January and December. But from the calculation it looks like in February we have saved less than December. I don't understand why because December over November looks quite realistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

[image]

[image]

Measure 1

```
Fixed Amount = 
 var fixedAmount = CALCULATE(SUM(Data[Cost]), FILTER(ALL(Data), Data[UsageDate]= DATE(2022,11,30)))

 RETURN  IF(NOT(ISBLANK(SUM(Data[Cost]))) && MIN(Data[UsageDate])>= DATE(2022,11,30), fixedAmount)
```

Measure 2

```
Delta = IF(NOT(ISBLANK(SUM(Data[Cost]))) && MIN(Data[UsageDate])>= DATE(2022,11,30), SUMX(VALUES(Data[UsageDate]),[Fixed Amount] - CALCULATE(SUM(Data[Cost])) ))
```

Comment: Hello, I added a file. I noticed that `'Usage details'[date].[Month] = "November"` works while the date `30/11/2022` didn't select the month. The problem is now that for November the costs are at 0. I should instead have the month of November or the 30/11/2022 to cover Dec, Jan, Feb, etc..

Comment: I'd need a .pbix to help further so I can see how everything is set up.

Comment: Hi David, and thank you for your help. I uploaded the raw data and the .pbix . 
Let me know if there is anything I can do for you.

Comment: Hello and thank you. I have a proper date table. But what is wrong with the one I sent you? There are Years, Quarters, Months, Days. There is everything we want, right?

Comment: Regarding the star schema, well, the data are pulled from the Azure Cost Management connector in Power BI Desktop: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-connect-azure-cost-management 
The data are unstructured and are more for a NoSQL database than for a RDBMS. But thank you for your help

Comment: Do you know why my matrix is now missing the row name: https://snipboard.io/fKzqYd.jpg

Comment: The file you sent me had a single table named "Data". There was no separate date table. You need fact tables and dimension tables (one of which is Date) in PowerBI to have reliable results.

Comment: I know why: the matrix visual doesn't show the row title if you only have 1 line. That is ugly and might be a bug.

Comment: Hi @David, while your calculation was right I realized that as soon as I use I wider number of months there is something strange: the numbers keep decreasing. And I don't see why. In February we should have definitely saved more money than in December. See picture. Thank you

Comment: Can you share an updated .pbix.

Comment: I did, I changed the links to the 2 files. Thank you

Comment: Another week is nearly over and I haven't been fired. Your last update worked and I thank you so much David. Time to take some Power BI course.