# Power BI matrix doesn't show Total or Grand Total for certain rows

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop

I have lately [received help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75866108/power-bi-calculate-delta-for-baseline-of-a-specific-date) in creating a DAX query that could help me calculate the delta between two lines.

While the Totals for the last line are OK for the first two lines are missing:

[image]

Have you ever seem something like this?

EDIT: Hi David, seems like you and I we are the only fish in the pond:

- [.xlsx](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArldK_gE2gPUkch-2ANoTw2Hh8GBhQ?e=RE4PRc)
- [.pbix](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArldK_gE2gPUkckJcrd-5cBMTl3VRw?e=LFCc5M)

Strangely I cannot put the columns of the Matrix back as they were in my screenshot.

The idea is to have one month per column and the total at the end.

Also, Is it possible to remove the "Total" between December and January?

Comment: Can you add a .pbix?

Comment: Hi @DavidBacci, I uploaded both. Thank you for your help

Comment: Hi @DavidBacci, I uploaded a new .pbix . I basically changed the link

Comment: Link doesn't work for me.

Comment: Sorry @DavidBacci, new link provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing in your .pbix what you show in the screenshot so not sure of the problem. To configure the totals as you wish, do the following:

Select column subtotals, and turn on per column level settings. Select Month from drop down and select off for Show subtotal.

[image]

[image]

EDIT|

If you want this:

[image]

Use this measure.

```
Delta2 = 
 VAR tbl = FILTER(Data, Data[UsageDate] >= DATE(2022,11,30))
 RETURN
 IF(NOT(ISBLANK(SUM(Data[Cost])))  ,  CALCULATE( SUMX( VALUES( Data[UsageDate]),[Fixed Amount] - CALCULATE(SUM(Data[Cost])) ), tbl))
```