# Power BI :: How to switch stacked area chart

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I've been helped extensively about [how to calculate delta for baseline of a specific date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75866108/power-bi-calculate-delta-for-baseline-of-a-specific-date) .

And thanks to that help my Power BI dashboard looks very pretty:

[image]

But I have 3 metrics to compare:

- Realized savings dev
- Realized savings prod
- Realized savings test

And I would like the stacked are chart to switch to dev / prod / test with a click.

But how to do so? That stacked are chart is created by these 2 measures and I can only drag and drop manually:

[image]

Can I use a slicer? How?

Or a custom stacked are chart for each measure and a drop down menu that allows to switch? How?

If you want to help me you can download the files here:

- [.pbix](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArldK_gE2gPUkcwioDIJzDoA4hiIJA?e=hSrmbO)
- [.xlsx](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArldK_gE2gPUkcwhkUIUR5Bz9ZjXcg?e=Fdt2tn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new ref table called `Environment` containing the 3 values "PROD", "TEST" and "DEV".

And then Create a new measure:

```
Realised Saving = SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE(Environment[environment]),"PROD",[Realised Savings prod],"TEST",[Realised Savings test],"DEV",[Realised Savings dev],0)
```

This measure should change based on slice input

Here's a [.pbix](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArrAd8YLEPFqikf9WKrcChgyKMLB?e=46bdwd)

Comment: Thank you @Doedi, I tried to create a measure with that code but the table generated by it doesn't want to enter into a slicer

Comment: You need to create the table before creating the measure

Comment: Nothing as you can see: https://snipboard.io/jb9wDd.jpg

Comment: I added a file exemple

Comment: Thank you. As you can see DEV and TEST are broken and they don't show in the stacked area chart: https://snipboard.io/YV8zT7.jpg . This because while `RealisedSavings` can move dynamically the same doesn't work for `Realised savings prod Delta`. The goal is to move 2 metrics at the same time because both are creating the stacked area chart.

Comment: You need to to the same for `Delta`, ie create a new measure