# Power BI :: How to calculate delta forecast

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop, forecasting

A good soul helped me create this [Power BI :: calculate delta for baseline of a specific date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75866108/power-bi-calculate-delta-for-baseline-of-a-specific-date) and the result was a success.

But what I would like to do now is to forecast the calculation till the end of the year.

[image]

How to extend the 2 lines of the forecasting and the relative delta calculation to the 31 Dec 2023?

Here the:

- [.pbix](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArldK_gE2gPUkcwioDIJzDoA4hiIJA?e=jwy7d2)
- [.xlsx](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArldK_gE2gPUkcwhkUIUR5Bz9ZjXcg?e=VVZarN)

Comment: I can see in the pbix file and Excel file you've shared that the max of usage date is the 31 March 2023? do you have data that covers the interval until 31 Dec 2023

Comment: Hi and thank you for your interest. Yes, I have data of the last 3 years but what I'm uploading here is just a moking of my real data. I only need the calculation of the forecast in DAX and I will later add that to my real dashboard

Comment: Is it possible to provide a solution using python? Because when you say forecast it's somehow predicting the future

Comment: Yes but I'm sure there must be a way to do it easily with DAX.

Answer (score 0):

Ref I used to figure out the steps:
https://towardsdatascience.com/forecasting-in-power-bi-4cc0b3568443

I have done some research and can simplify the steps:

To extend the lines of forecasting and the relative delta calculation to the 31st of December 2023, you would need to generate a forecast model using Power BI's built-in forecasting tool:

1. Pre the data data: Ensure your data is a time series data
   (consisting of a sequence of numerical data points in successive
   order), which is required for the forecasting.
2. Use a line chart: Put the date field on the axis and the measure you want to forecast on
   the values.
3. Turn on forecasting: In the visualizations pane, select the "Analytics" pane, then click on "Add" in the "Forecast" section.
4. Set forecasting parameters: Configure the parameters according to
   your needs. Here, you can set the forecast length to extend until
   the end of 2023. You can also adjust the confidence interval and
   seasonality.
5. Apply forecast: Click "Apply" to create the forecast.
   After the forecast has been generated, you can calculate the
   relative delta using similar DAX measures you previously used, but
   applying them to the forecasted data.

forecasting is a complex task that depends heavily on your data. The forecasting tool in Power BI is the best place to start, but it might not meet the complexity of your data, if you have complex time series data that has many factors you might need to consider using custom DAX calculations or integrating with external machine learning models.

here are the Microsoft docs to explain the fundamentals of how to do what you need here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-analytics-pane

**Update**

My research covered how to create a forecast using the built-in forecasting tool in Power BI. However, to calculate the delta (difference) between the forecast and actual values, you may need to create a separate measure using Data Analysis Expressions, the formula language used in Power BI.

Once you've generated the forecast, you can calculate the delta by subtracting the actual values from the forecasted values. This would give you the difference or "delta" for each corresponding time period.

Example DAX formula to calculate the delta:

```
Delta = [Forecasted Value] - [Actual Value]
```

To display the delta (the difference between actual values and forecasted values) on the same visual as the forecast can be done by creating calculated fields for the actual, forecast, and delta values, then plotting these on the same graph:

1. Create your forecast: Use the forecasting feature in Power BI to create a forecast for your data. selecting a line chart visual and expanding the Forecast section of the Analytics pane. Adjust the inputs to create your forecast.
2. Create a measure for the actual values: Create a measure that
   calculates the actual values of the variable you are forecasting.This measure will plot the actual data on the graph.
3. Create a measure for the forecasted values: This measure will be used to plot the forecast on the graph.
4. Create a measure for the
   delta: Create a measure that calculates the difference (delta)
   between the actual values and the forecasted values. Use the example above
5. Plot the measures on the same graph: Add a line chart to your report, then add the Actual, Forecast, and Delta measures to the Values field well of the chart. Power BI will automatically plot these three measures on the graph.

Comment: Thank you but this is not what I need, the calculation is more complex. Is not just drawing that line

Comment: please show your work and your effort in detail as you update your post.