# Power BI :: Create forecast on Stacked area chart & Matrix

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop

I've been [helped endlessly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75866108/power-bi-calculate-delta-for-baseline-of-a-specific-date) by Davide Bacci and his trick is at the very core of my dashboard.

This year I would like to add a forecast so I can see what will be the cost reduction for the year 2024.

I have 2 years of data and this is a good starting point on which I can base the forecast:

[image]

> POSSIBLE APPROACH

I did my investigation and I have 2 options in my head:

1. **The hard way:** Create a forecast based on the last 2 years of data, [something like this](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/showing-actuals-and-forecasts-in-the-same-chart-with-power-bi/) . It doesn't look easy but it would be the best.
2. **The easy way:** using the [moving average](https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/financial-modeling/forecasting-methods/) which will be based on the previous month and will move dynamically.

> PROBLEM

How can I create a forecast and:

- Create a line on the stacked area chart that keeps going till the end of 2024. In my understanding I should create 2 lines: one for `Realised Savings Log Analytics Delta` and one for `Realised Savings Log Analytics Fixed Amount`
- List the forecast for each month on the Matrix

You can download the data here:

- [azmon.csv](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArldK_gE2gPUmKZEtIibQxdWK6EoSg?e=q2fBeN)
- [azmon.pbix](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArldK_gE2gPUmKZFFM6Pi3W9oR1Q7g?e=YLG8dR)

**EDIT:** The DAX measure to modify is this:

```
RETURN  IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Realised Savings Log Analytics])) && MIN('cost-management-export'[date])>= DATE(2023,12,19), ave)
```

And I modified to:

```
RETURN IF(
    NOT(ISBLANK([Realised Savings Log Analytics])) && 
    MIN('cost-management-export'[date]) >= DATE(2023,12,19) && 
    MIN('cost-management-export'[date]) <= DATE(2024,12,12),
    ave
)
```

But it's still not working.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: What's your definition for Forecast? Is it you simply want to use the avg of the last month and have it projected to end of 2024 (so a straight line)?

Comment: @SamNseir : you can find that in point 1 and 2. Point 1: the hard way, a forecast for 2024 based on the data of 2022 and 2023. Point 2: the easy way: the moving average, a forecast based on the last 3 months and that moves ahead each month.

Comment: @SamNseir for each forecast I have a link that explains how to do it. I would prefer the point 1

Comment: Action taken in Dec'23, are you expecting the numbers to drop in 2024? Current forecast is looking like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFqsh.png is that what you're expecting? If not, will you be providing approx numbers for 2024 for forecast like Option 1 above?